# Why do I get a type error (InvalidOperationException) when sending a viewmodel to a partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

When I try to send a model view to my own partial view, it gives an error that their types are not the same.

See this is my service:

```
  public Category GetCategoryByCategoryURL(string url)
        {
            return _context.
                Categories.
                Where(c=>c.CategoryURL== "https://localhost:44374/"+url)
                .Single();
        }
```

Which works without any problems. The bottom part of my controller is:

```
 [Route("/{url}")]
        public IActionResult CategoryChooser(string url)
        {
            Category cat = _categoryService.GetCategoryByCategoryURL(url);
            return View(cat);
        }
```

Picks up the category and sends it to the main view. This is the main view:

```
@using PipeLandProject.Core.DTOs.Category
@model PipeLandProject.DataLayer.Entities.Category.Category
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = Model.CategoryTitle;

}
<div class="container">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/">صفحه اصلی</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">@Model.CategoryTitle</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <h1>@Model.CategoryTitle</h1>
            <p>@Model.CategoryContent</p>
            <h3>آیدی دسته: @Model.CategoryId</h3>
            <img src="/CategoryImage/Image/@Model.CategoryImageName" alt="@Model.CategoryTitle">
            <p>@Model.CategoryMetaDescription</p>
            <a href="@Model.CategoryURL" title="@Model.CategoryTitle">آدرس صفحه</a>
            <img src="/CategoryImage/DemoFile/@Model.DemoFileName" alt="@Model.CategoryTitle"/>
            @*<partial name="ListCategory" />
            <partial name="CategoryContent" />*@
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

When I run it goes without any problems but I want to use partial.
This page has 2 sections. One part is a list of the main categories of the site and the other part is the content of the same category. Now the ViewModel is as follows:

```
 public class ShowListCategoryViewModel
    {
        public string CategoryTitle { get; set; }
    }
```

service:

```
 public List<ShowListCategoryViewModel> ShowAllCategoryForSideBar()
        {
            return _context.Categories.Select(
                c => new ShowListCategoryViewModel()
                {
                    CategoryTitle = c.CategoryTitle
                }).ToList();
        }
```

and view this partial:

```
@model PipeLandProject.Core.DTOs.Category.ShowListCategoryViewModel
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
    <div class="position-sticky px-0 mx-0">
        <h2 class="h4 font-weight-bold">دسته بندی سایت</h2>
        <hr/>
        <ul class="list-group shadow">

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CategoryTitle.Length; i++)
            {
                <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <a href="" class="">@Model.CategoryTitle</a>
                    <span class="px-2 badge badge-primary badge-pill">12</span>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second part of the page:

Content section of the model view page:

```
 public class ShowCategoryContentViewModel
    {
        public string CategoryTitle { get; set; }
        public string CategoryImageName { get; set; }
        public string CategoryContent { get; set; }
        public string DemoFile { get; set; }
    }
```

service:

```
public ShowCategoryContentViewModel ShowContentOfCategory(string url)
        {
            return _context.Categories
                .Where(c => c.CategoryURL == url)
                .Select(c=>new ShowCategoryContentViewModel()
                {
                    CategoryImageName = c.CategoryImageName,
                    CategoryContent = c.CategoryContent,
                    CategoryTitle = c.CategoryTitle,
                    DemoFile = c.DemoFileName
                })
                .Single();
        }
```

partial view:

```
@model PipeLandProject.Core.DTOs.Category.ShowCategoryContentViewModel

<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
    <h1 class="font-weight-bold">@Model.CategoryTitle</h1>
    <hr />
    <p>
        @Model.CategoryContent
    </p>
    <img src="/CategoryImage/@Model.CategoryImageName" />
</div>
```

This error shows the following.
It does not allow running at all. In general, I want to pass the model view to the partial view.
[image: error partial 1]

Error text if I do not send the model to the partials:
[image: error partial 2]

My project consists of 3 layers
The first layer is the core, which is related to the database. In this layer, there are model views and other parts such as interfaces and services.
The second layer is the database layer
And the third layer is the web layer, which is related to the core layer.
I used interfaces in the core layer and its service was implemented in the same layer.
The following code is the complete service section for categories:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using PipeLandProject.Core.Convertors;
using PipeLandProject.Core.DTOs.Category;
using PipeLandProject.Core.Generator;
using PipeLandProject.Core.Security;
using PipeLandProject.Core.Services.Interfaces;
using PipeLandProject.DataLayer.Context;
using PipeLandProject.DataLayer.Entities.Category;

namespace PipeLandProject.Core.Services
{
    public class CategoryService : ICategoryService
    {
        private PipeLandProjectContext _context;

        public CategoryService(PipeLandProjectContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public int AddCategory(Category category)
        {
            _context.Categories.Add(category);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return category.CategoryId;
        }

        public int AddCategory(Category category, IFormFile imgCategory, IFormFile categoryDemo)
        {
            category.CategoryImageName = "default.png";
            if (imgCategory != null && imgCategory.IsImage())
            {
                category.CategoryImageName=
                    NameGenerator.GenerateUniqCode() + Path.GetExtension(imgCategory.FileName);
                string imagePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/CategoryImage/Image/", category.CategoryImageName);

                using (var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    imgCategory.CopyTo(stream);
                }
                #region Image Resize

                ImageConvertor imgResizer = new ImageConvertor();
                string ThumbPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/CategoryImage/Thumb/", category.CategoryImageName);

                imgResizer.Image_resize(imagePath, ThumbPath, 150);

                #endregion
                #region UpLoad Demo File

                if (categoryDemo != null)
                {
                    category.DemoFileName =
                        NameGenerator.GenerateUniqCode() + Path.GetExtension(categoryDemo.FileName);
                    string demoPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/CategoryImage/DemoFile/", category.DemoFileName);
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(demoPath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        categoryDemo.CopyTo(stream);
                    }
                }

                #endregion
            }
            _context.Categories.Add(category);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return category.CategoryId;
        }

        public int AddCategoryFromAdmin(CreateCategoryViewModel category, IFormFile imgCategory, IFormFile categoryDemo)
        {
            Category addCategory = new Category();
            addCategory.CategoryTitle = category.CategoryTitle;
            addCategory.CategoryContent = category.CategoryContent;
            addCategory.CategoryMetaDescription = category.CategoryMetaDescription;
            addCategory.CategoryURL = category.CategoryURL;
            //if (category.CategoryImage != null)
            //{
            //    string imagePath = "";
            //    addCategory.CategoryImageName = NameGenerator.GenerateUniqCode() + Path.GetExtension(category.CategoryImage.FileName);
            //    imagePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/CategoryImage", addCategory.CategoryImageName);
            //    using (var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Create))
            //    {
            //        category.CategoryImage.CopyTo(stream);
            //    }
            //}
            addCategory.CategoryImageName = "default.png";
            if (imgCategory != null && imgCategory.IsImage())
            {
                addCategory.CategoryImageName =
                    NameGenerator.GenerateUniqCode() + Path.GetExtension(imgCategory.FileName);
                string imagePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/CategoryImage/Image/", addCategory.CategoryImageName);

                using (var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    imgCategory.CopyTo(stream);
                }
                #region Image Resize

                ImageConvertor imgResizer = new ImageConvertor();
                string ThumbPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/CategoryImage/Thumb/", addCategory.CategoryImageName);

                imgResizer.Image_resize(imagePath, ThumbPath, 150);

            }
            #endregion
            #region UpLoad Demo File
            if (categoryDemo != null)
            {
                addCategory.DemoFileName =
                    NameGenerator.GenerateUniqCode() + Path.GetExtension(categoryDemo.FileName);
                string demoPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/CategoryImage/DemoFile/", addCategory.DemoFileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(demoPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    categoryDemo.CopyTo(stream);
                }
            }
            #endregion
            _context.Categories.Add(addCategory);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return addCategory.CategoryId;
        }

        public void DeleteCategory(int categoryId)
        {
            Category category = GetCategoryByCategoryId(categoryId);
            category.IsDelete = true;
            UpdateCategory(category);
        }

        public void EditCategoryFromAdmin(EditCategoryForAdminViewModel edit)
        {
            Category category = GetCategoryByCategoryId(edit.CategoryId);
            category.CategoryTitle = edit.CategoryTitle;
            category.CategoryURL = edit.CategoryTitle;
            category.CategoryContent = edit.CategoryContent;
            category.CategoryMetaDescription = edit.CategoryMetaDescription;
          

            if (edit.CategoryImageName != null)
            {
                #region Delete Old Image Category   
                if (edit.CategoryImageName != "Default.jpg")
                {
                    string deletePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/CategoryImage", edit.CategoryImageName);
                    if (File.Exists(deletePath))
                    {
                        File.Delete(deletePath);
                    }
                }
                #endregion

                #region Save New Image Category
                //category.CategoryImageName = NameGenerator.GenerateUniqCode() + Path.GetExtension(edit.CategoryImage.FileName);
                //string imagePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/CategoryImage", category.CategoryImageName);
                //using (var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Create))
                //{
                //    edit.CategoryImageName.CopyTo(stream);
                //}
                #endregion

            }
            _context.Categories.Update(category);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }


        public List<ShowCategoryForAdminViewModel> GetCategoriesForAdmin()
        {
            return _context.Categories.Where(p => !p.IsDelete)
                .Select(p => new ShowCategoryForAdminViewModel()
                {
                    CategoryId = p.CategoryId,
                    CategoryImageName = p.CategoryImageName,
                    CategoryTitle = p.CategoryTitle,
                    CategoryURL = p.CategoryURL,
                    CategoryMetaDescription = p.CategoryMetaDescription
                }).ToList();
        }

        public Category GetCategoryByCategoryId(int id)
        {
            return _context.Categories.Find(id);
        }

        public Category GetCategoryByCategoryTitle(string title)
        {
            return _context.Categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CategoryTitle == title);
        }

        public Category GetCategoryByCategoryURL(string url)
        {
            return _context.
                Categories.
                Where(c=>c.CategoryURL== "https://localhost:44374/"+url)
                .Single();
        }

        public EditCategoryForAdminViewModel GetCategoryForManageCategory(Category category)
        {
            //var categoryId = GetCategoryByCategoryId(category.CategoryId);
            //_context.Categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CategoryId == categoryId)
            //    .Select(p => new EditCategoryForAdminViewModel
            //    {
            //        CategoryImageName = p.
            //    });




            return null;
        }

        public bool isExistCategoryURL(string url)
        {
            return _context.Categories.Any(c => c.CategoryURL == url);
        }

        public ShowCategory ShowAllCategory(string url)
        {
            var category = GetCategoryByCategoryURL(url);
            var cat = new Category()
            {
                CategoryTitle = _context.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryTitle == category.CategoryTitle).ToString(),
                CategoryImageName = _context.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryImageName == category.CategoryImageName)
                    .ToString(),
                CategoryContent = _context.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryContent == category.CategoryContent).ToString(),
                CategoryMetaDescription = _context.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryMetaDescription == category.CategoryMetaDescription).ToString(),
                DemoFileName = _context.Categories.Select(c => c.DemoFileName == category.DemoFileName).ToString()
            };
            







            //return _context.Categories.Select(c => new ShowCategory()
            //{
            //   Category = 
            //}).ToList();
        }

        public List<ShowListCategoryViewModel> ShowAllCategoryForSideBar()
        {
            return _context.Categories.Select(
                c => new ShowListCategoryViewModel()
                {
                    CategoryTitle = c.CategoryTitle
                }).ToList();
        }

        public ShowCategoryContentViewModel ShowContentOfCategory(string url)
        {
            return _context.Categories
                .Where(c => c.CategoryURL == url)
                .Select(c=>new ShowCategoryContentViewModel()
                {
                    CategoryImageName = c.CategoryImageName,
                    CategoryContent = c.CategoryContent,
                    CategoryTitle = c.CategoryTitle,
                    DemoFile = c.DemoFileName
                })
                .Single();
        }

        public void UpdateCategory(Category category)
        {
            _context.Update(category);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create a view model that contains 3 models-  1 for main view and 2 models for partial views

```
public class ViewModel
{
 public  Category Category  {get;set;}
 public List<ShowListCategoryViewModel>  ShowListCategoryViewModel {get;set;}
 public ShowCategoryContentViewModel ShowCategoryContentViewModel {get;set;}
 
}
```

and you have to fill all 3 models in your  action for the main view

```
        [Route("/{url}")]
        public IActionResult CategoryChooser(string url)
        {
            var model= new  ViewModel();
            model.Category = _categoryService.GetCategoryByCategoryURL(url);
            model.ShowCategoryContentViewModel= ShowContentOfCategory(url)
            model.ShowListCategoryViewModel= ShowAllCategoryForSideBar();
            return View(model);
        }
```

after this fix models of  main view

```
@model ViewModel

..... use @Model.Category for  the main view controls

......

<partial name="ListCategory", @Model.ShowListCategoryViewModel />
<partial name="CategoryContent", @Model.ShowCategoryContentViewModel/>
```

Update

```
 public Category ShowAllCategory(string url)
        {

        return    _context.Categories
                .Where(c=>c.CategoryURL== "https://localhost:44374/"+url)
                .Select(c=> = new Category
               {
                CategoryTitle = c.CategoryTitle
                CategoryImageName = c.CategoryImageName
                CategoryContent = c.CategoryContent,
                CategoryMetaDescription =  c.CategoryMetaDescription,
               DemoFileName = c.DemoFileName 
             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you. It was very useful for me.
Is it possible to write down the service part (using the database to fetch results)? @Sergey

Comment: I mean the help for Section EF core. public ShowCategory ShowAllCategory(string url)
        {
            var category = GetCategoryByCategoryURL(url);
            var cat = new Category()
            {
                CategoryTitle = _context.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryTitle == category.CategoryTitle).ToString(),
                CategoryImageName = _context.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryImageName == category.CategoryImageName)
                    .ToString(),
                CategoryContent = _context.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryContent == category.CategoryContent).To S

Comment: Sorry, but what about Section EF core. I don' t know what it is and I can't see any  Section in your code.

Comment: Can you post it please as update to your question? It's hard to read in comments

Comment: Post updated. i need help in ( ShowAllCategory )

Comment: I added get Category. If you have a class ShowCategory pls pablish it too.